# Generate Oncoprint

Tags: r, complexheatmap

I'd like to create an Oncoprint like in this manual https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/oncoprint.html#apply-to-cbioportal-dataset under Section 7.2. Unfortunately, when applying the same code with my own dataset, I get errors all the time that I don't understand at all. I'm very inexperienced using R and only deal with it once in a while, hence me being at a loss pretty often when confronted with complex codes.

Now, this is my dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mZi6i9VP6CY-BgGrBw8aF9Ow3-i-ElBoXd8uPCyo5P8/edit?usp=sharing - I tried to replicate the same format that is used in the manual. I know that rows and colums need to be swapped to be identical to the example used in the manual, but I doubt that's what is causing the errors (or is it?).

Now when I try to replicate what's written in the example like so

```
col = c("Missense" = "blue", "Deletion" = "red", "Nonsense" = "#008000", "DelIns" = "yellow", "Frameshift" = "pink", "Splice site" = "brown")
```

and continue to add arguments to the example given by copy-pasting and simply changing the bits that represent my own data I get the following error: "Error in list(background = function(x, y, w, h) { : argument 8 is empty". Naturally, the following codes won't work as well.

Now, I should mention as well that after installing the required packages (which should be ComplexHeatmap and BiocManager) I get another error when loading ComplexHeatmap with `library()` that says 'Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ComplexHeatmap’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘GetoptLong’`. I have no idea if this somehow affects the whole matter.

Oh and this `alter_graphic()` function mentioned in the guide can not be found. I understood that it comes with the package and doesn't need to be defined on my own.

As you can see, I'm totally confused and have no idea what to do. Any help would mean a lot to me!